PHP iOS message structure - changed? user_action doesn't seem to work as before
I used to use: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with the following code:
$notifBody = [
  'to' => $fcmToken,
  'time_to_live' => 3600,
  'notification' => [
   'title' => "$my_title",
   'body' => "$my_body",
   'icon' => "$my_icon",
   'sound' => "$my_sound",
   'user_action' => "$my_clickAction"
 ]
];

I'd JSON encode $notifyBody and send via CURL. Worked like champ.
Since good ole' Firebase / Google decided to change things, and now that I'm authenticating using the Goggle API auth client, things just aren't the same.
New code:
$message = [
    "message" => [
    "notification" => [
        "title" => "$push_data->my_title",
        "body" => "$push_data->my_body",
    ],
    "apns" => [
        "headers" => [
            "apsn-priority" => '10',
        ],
        "payload" => [
            "aps" => [
                "sound" => "$push_data->my_sound",
                "user_action" => "$push_data->my_click_action",
            ],
        ],
    ],
    "android" => [
        "priority" => 'high',
        "notification" => [
            "sound" => "$push_data->my_sound",
        ],
    ],
    "token" => "$push_data->fcm_token",
    ],
];

Now posting to https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$project}/messages:send
I get the push notification on iOS, but I cannot find/decipher where "user_action" goes within the new code. When I tap the push notification, it just opens the app, where prior, it would open whatever I had set to "user_action".

Caveat: Not familiar with this service.
The FCM REST API documents the send method, its request body including the Message type.
AndroidNotification includes a click_action
ApnsNotification includes a payload and the documentation links to Apple's Payload key reference which may be what you need to configure for similar behavior on iOS.
Google's documentation provides an example: targeting multiple platforms which references Apple notification.click_action in the "before" but is unclear on how this maps in the "after". Unless NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY is an instance of a JSON payload using Apple's Payload key reference.
